# Google assistant and opening unlunched app

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, google-assistant

I want open an app that we haved coded without realse it in play store with Google assistant,
Is it possible?
Cuz when say app name it doesn't recognize our app and go to search section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can open your which is not published on play store with google assistant.
I have tried it with my apps and it works fine.

Just make sure your are pronouncing the name correctly.
you can also say **" Open *App Name* from my device"** so it will not go for search.

[I uploaded a small video demonstrating google assistant opening an **unpublished** app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fZa3Y_Bijft0rIvGvACSEehi_qLaqdmv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It works just fine on my device , would you like to see a video of opening a new test app?

Comment: @Ayon Check the link I updated in the Answer

Comment: It's work correctly in your device ,but in my doesn't. how you named class in your app

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what you meant by "How you named class in your app"  if you meant how I named my app/or _how you can change the name of the app_ , go to the String Resource folder(**app>res>values>strings.xml**)  and change the tag with name="app_name" to anything you want.